# SSIS expression to select data between two symbols without hardcoding

Tags: sql-server

I have expression with data and underscores, there is an integer between cursors and that integer varies according to data. I want that integer part without hardcoding and need to be updated according to the data.

Comment: Add sample data, expected result, and what you've tried so far to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean a pipe symbol, you can do this with SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX

The syntax is SUBSTRING(string, startpos, length)

To get the startpos, you need to find the location of the first pipe and add a character to exclude the pipe from the result.   Endpos is a bit trickier - you need to discard the first part of the string using the RIGHT function, then find the position of the pipe in the remaining part to get the length.

```
select substring(col1, charindex('|',col1)+1, 
                 charindex('|',right(col1,len(col1)-charindex('|',col1)))-1)
from testdata
```

See fiddle for worked example

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8affa/23

Comment: The OP at least was clear that they needed an SSIS expression. They haven't, however, been clear on anything else.

Comment: is this works if (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8affa/23) output data size more than the input, i mean in this link you replaced 1231 to 4. Is this work in vice-versa?

Comment: @File Name: 20171230_1_Estimate.xlsx in this i need to extract 1 without hard coded and be updated irrespective if size